# comma seperated values in string to vector - Java

Tags: java, string, vector, iterator

In java how can i convert a string with comma separating values into a vector. So when a comma is encountered in the string, that value is added to the vector

Comment: Have you tried using String method called split()? something like string.split(",").. This will return an array which you can later use to fill the vector object

Comment: And by "vector" do you mean a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)) or a [`Vector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)?

Comment: Feel free to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
String s = "1, 2, 3, 4";
String[] sa = s.split(",");

Vector vec = new Vector();
vec.addAll(Arrays.asList(sa));
```

Answer (score 1):

As justRadojko suggested, you can use the String's method .split(). Turning this into an List would be trivial:

```
String[] temp = string.split(",");
for(String s : temp){
    list.add(s);
}
```

Comment: [`Arrays.asList(temp)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...))